# Notifications logo not showing when my app is closed

Tags: react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, message

```
 const displayNotification = async message => {
    // Request permissions (required for iOS)
    await notifee.requestPermission();

    // Create a channel (required for Android)
    const channelId = await notifee.createChannel({
      id: 'default',
      name: 'Default Channel',
      badge: true,
    });

    // Display a notification
    await notifee.displayNotification({
      title: message.title,
      body: message.body,
      android: {
        channelId,
        smallIcon: 'ic_notification',
        largeIcon: 'ic_notification',
        color: '#ff8f00',
        pressAction: {
          id: 'default1',
          intent: {
            action: 'android.intent.action.MAIN',
            category: ['android.intent.category.LAUNCHER'],
            packageName: 'com.example.myapp',
            className: 'com.example.myapp.MainActivity',
          },
        },
      },
    });
  };

  return {token, displayNotification};
};
```

I am sending notification to my app using notifee and firebase messaing. When I send a notification when the application is open, the logo appears, but when the application is closed, a square logo appears. How can i fix it?